# cascaded dropdown in struts

Tags: struts

I have to design a web page using struts.
I have to show two dropdowns.
The data in the first dropdown will be populated dynamically from database. This part is completed.
I have to populate the data in second dropdown based on the selection in 1st dropdown.

I need help for this development since I am new to struts technology.

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: It might help to post the code you have written so far for this step.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use ajax to load data to the dropdown2 by invoking it in the onchange method for dropdown1

DropDown1:
----------

    <s:select key="label.name" list="list1" onchange="reloadView();" name="id" id="list">
    </s:select>

reloadView()
------------

try {
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
                    catch (e) 
                {
                try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } 
                catch (e) 
                {
                                alert("Your browser has no AJAX Support!");
                    return false;
                }
        }
        }
    var url = "yourUrl";
    ajaxRequest.open("POST", url, true);
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        try 
        {
                if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
                        var res = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                        if (res) 
                        {
                                document.getElementById("yourDiv").innerHTML = res;
                                adjustTable();
                        }
                }
        } 
        catch (e) 
        {

        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.send(null);

DropDown2
---------

    <div id="yourDiv">
    <s:select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Yes I can use Ajax. But how can I get the value in the Action Class if I will use HTML dropdown for 2nd one. I want two objects for two dropdowns in my Action class.

Comment: This is what you should do, action1.action will load data for dropdown1 and redirect the page to a jsp. In the dropdown 1 you will call another action class or the same action class (but call a different method or identify the call using a parameter that differentiates this call from the call to load dropdown1's data), which will load data for dropdown2.

Comment: Hi Pradeep,
But can you please tell me how can I call an action in onchange event of an dropdown?

Comment: You can have a look at the code in my reply to your question. You have to replace 'yourUrl' with the action class.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. Now I get your reply properly.

Comment: Can you please help me by explaining how to form the URL and also what should be in the struts.xml for this kind of action. Since I am new to Struts i need help from you guys.